# changing the text of the watch action button for android tv search results

Tags: android, search, android-tv

Ive built an app for android tv that allows for global search results to be returned from a search query started from the android tv home screen. It works fine but Im having trouble changing the text within the watch action button. I noticed that crackle watch action results that show when my apps watch action results show have the word FREE in the button but no matter what I do I cant change the text in the button from my app so it always says AVAILABLE ON. I need to know how to change this text.

So does anyone know how to change the text of the watch action buttons in the search result fragment in the global search on android tv?

Comment: Are you referring to [Deep Linking](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable.html#details)? You can customize where it links too, but I'm not sure about the actual button.

Comment: exactly. I need to change the text of that button. Crackle has figured it out so I know it must be possible.

Comment: The [leanback sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) might do it too. I believe it opens it's [own fragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/058d880f82ba8c92bdeb1e3cd44a9eea695b28ba/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/SearchFragment.java) (see ItemViewClickedListener) when checking for details in search. You may have to implement something similar.

Comment: Yeah Ive looked that over quite a bit but I dont think that searchfragment gets used in global search. the searchfragment class gets used within the sample app. That main card/fragment that shows after a search from the nexus player home screen is some system thing.

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth emails with google engineers it looks like you cannot change the text of that watch action button in the search results for your app right now. I did submit a feature request but I have no idea if it will ever get implemented.